# Unresolved External Symbol errors while using Catch2

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, linker-errors, catch2

I am trying to do Catch2 Unit Testing in Visual Studio. I have created a small test project to practice. When I try to compile this test project, I get a linker error. I am now trying to diagnose this linker error, but the `Catch2.hpp` header file contains thousands of lines of code. My hope is that someone who is more familiar with Catch2 or unit testing in general can diagnose what the issue is.

I will describe the process by which I created this project. I created a new project in a new solution. I have 4 files, all in the same directory, listed below.

The class I want to test:

```
//a.h

#pragma once

class A {
    friend int A_Tester_Func1(A a);
public:
    A(int num) : my_num_(num) {
    }
private:
    int my_num_;
};
```

The test:

```
//atester.cpp

#pragma once

#include "catch.hpp"
#include "a.h"

int A_Tester_Func1(A a) {
    return a.my_num_;
}

TEST_CASE("a contains a positive integer", "[a]") {
    //...
    A a(3);
    REQUIRE(A_Tester_Func1(a) == 3);

}
```

The main function that runs the tests:

```
//tester.cpp

#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp" // this should create the main function
```

The Catch2 Testing Framework:

```
// catch.hpp

/*
 *  Catch v2.13.2
 *  Generated: 2020-10-07 11:32:53.302017
*/

//~17-18k lines of code that from Catch2

#endif // TWOBLUECUBES_SINGLE_INCLUDE_CATCH_HPP_INCLUDED
```

When I try to compile this code in Visual Studio using the Local Windows Debugger button, I get a bunch of Unresolved External Symbol linker errors. I believe I read somewhere that Catch2 is "partially compiled." That may have something to do with it, but I don't know. Following this guide ([StackOverflow: Best practices for Unit testing with Catch2 in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645381/best-practices-for-unit-testing-with-catch2-in-visual-studio)) has worked for me, but I'm trying to understand why the small example above is not successfully linking.

I have included the linker errors below for completeness, although I feel that they will probably not be necessary for the question.

```
1>atester.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Catch::StringRef::StringRef(char const *)" (??0StringRef@Catch@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function "public: class Catch::BinaryExpr<int const &,int const &> const __thiscall Catch::ExprLhs<int const &>::operator==<int>(int const &)" (??$?8H@?$ExprLhs@ABH@Catch@@QAE?BV?$BinaryExpr@ABHABH@1@ABH@Z)
1>atester.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct Catch::ITestInvoker * __cdecl Catch::makeTestInvoker(void (__cdecl*)(void))" (?makeTestInvoker@Catch@@YAPAUITestInvoker@1@P6AXXZ@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'autoRegistrar1''(void)" (??__EautoRegistrar1@?A0xf9ca9c7d@@YAXXZ)
1>atester.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Catch::NameAndTags::NameAndTags(class Catch::StringRef const &,class Catch::StringRef const &)" (??0NameAndTags@Catch@@QAE@ABVStringRef@1@0@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'autoRegistrar1''(void)" (??__EautoRegistrar1@?A0xf9ca9c7d@@YAXXZ)
1>atester.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Catch::AutoReg::AutoReg(struct Catch::ITestInvoker *,struct Catch::SourceLineInfo const &,class Catch::StringRef const &,struct Catch::NameAndTags const &)" (??0AutoReg@Catch@@QAE@PAUITestInvoker@1@ABUSourceLineInfo@1@ABVStringRef@1@ABUNameAndTags@1@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'autoRegistrar1''(void)" (??__EautoRegistrar1@?A0xf9ca9c7d@@YAXXZ)
1>atester.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Catch::AutoReg::~AutoReg(void)" (??1AutoReg@Catch@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'autoRegistrar1''(void)" (??__FautoRegistrar1@?A0xf9ca9c7d@@YAXXZ)
1>atester.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl Catch::StringMaker<int,void>::convert(int)" (?convert@?$StringMaker@HX@Catch@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl Catch::Detail::stringify<int>(int const &)" (??$stringify@H@Detail@Catch@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABH@Z)
1>atester.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Catch::ITransientExpression::~ITransientExpression(void)" (??1ITransientExpression@Catch@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall Catch::BinaryExpr<int const &,int const &>::~BinaryExpr<int const &,int const &>(void)" (??1?$BinaryExpr@ABHABH@Catch@@UAE@XZ)
1>atester.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl Catch::formatReconstructedExpression(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class Catch::StringRef,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?formatReconstructedExpression@Catch@@YAXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@3@VStringRef@1@1@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall Catch::BinaryExpr<int const &,int const &>::streamReconstructedExpression(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?streamReconstructedExpression@?$BinaryExpr@ABHABH@Catch@@EBEXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>atester.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Catch::AssertionHandler::AssertionHandler(class Catch::StringRef const &,struct Catch::SourceLineInfo const &,class Catch::StringRef,enum Catch::ResultDisposition::Flags)" (??0AssertionHandler@Catch@@QAE@ABVStringRef@1@ABUSourceLineInfo@1@V21@W4Flags@ResultDisposition@1@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0(void)" (?____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0@@YAXXZ)
1>atester.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Catch::AssertionHandler::handleExpr(struct Catch::ITransientExpression const &)" (?handleExpr@AssertionHandler@Catch@@QAEXABUITransientExpression@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0(void)" (?____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0@@YAXXZ)
1>atester.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Catch::AssertionHandler::handleUnexpectedInflightException(void)" (?handleUnexpectedInflightException@AssertionHandler@Catch@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function __catch$?____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0@@YAXXZ$0
1>atester.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Catch::AssertionHandler::complete(void)" (?complete@AssertionHandler@Catch@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function __catch$?____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0@@YAXXZ$0
1>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
```

What is causing these errors? How do I fix these errors while keeping `catch.hpp` in the same project as my source files?

Answer (score 1):

In a .cpp file, add this to make the project a Catch2 test runner:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER
#include "catch.hpp"
```

Read more at [Supplying main() yourself](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/own-main.md#supplying-main-yourself)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see now that you already had #define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN. If that was missing, then I think it would cause the exact same errors. Perhaps the #define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN is not in exactly one place or not in the correct place in your project.

Comment: my solution was to move the catch2 tests to a separate project and compile my main project as a static library. I'm not sure if that is necessary (which is what the question is about), but it worked.

Comment: We have all our Catch2 tests in our application's executable project. So I know that can work fine. Not sure if that's the best practice though. I think I would prefer having them in a separate project, but then you might have to expose an API just for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.

You need to keep `#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN` in the first line of the file, especially before other #include.

Answer (score 0):

1. `atester.cpp` must not have the `#pragma once` directive. It's for header files, and while it may not be your source of trouble, it simply doesn't belong. Since you're not providing enough detail (namely: where's the minimized project file?), I have to be conservative here.
2. It seems that `tester.cpp` is not part of the project that you're building. Just because it's a file that exists on disk doesn't mean it's automatically picked up. You have to manually add it to the MSVC project. That's all there's to it. I use Catch2 with MSVS all the time and that's all it takes to make it work.